# Implement fallback incase original script is not found

Tags: javascript

My pages relies on this script currently:

script a)

```
<script  src="https://mipage.com/pathtoscript/owlscript.js"></script>
```

Incase loading this (script a) ) fails, I'd want to load:

script b)

```
<script  src="https://otherpage.com/pathtoscript/owlscript.js"></script>
```

Any way to do this ?

PS: I've seen [implementations for jsquery](https://builtvisible.com/setting-local-fallback-jquery-served-via-cdn/), but those won't work here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way for this is to listen for the [`error` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/error_event) of the first script tag. You can do this for example with the [`onerror` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror):

```html
<script src="https://mipage.com/pathtoscript/owlscript.js" onerror="loadFallbackScript()"></script>
```

and then loading the fallback script from code:

```js
function createScriptElement(src) {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = src;

    return script;
}

function loadFallbackScript() {
    const fallbackScriptElement = createScriptElement('fallback.js');
    document.head.append(fallbackScriptElement);
}
```

But since this requires `loadFallbackScript` to be a global function a cleaner way would be to create the first script tag dynamically as well and attach the event listener from code:

```js
// execute this instead of the <script> tag in the html
const externalScriptElement = createScriptElement('external.js');
externalScriptElement.addEventListener('error', loadFallbackScript);
document.head.append(externalScriptElement);
```

Comment: Can this be invoked from within a html via <script></script> tag ? I'd like to keeps as lowkey as possible. Otherwisew: Great answer.

Comment: Of course, you can inline this JavaScript directly into the html within a `<script>` tag.